# Get the count of number of options populated in the dropdown of django change_form.html template

Tags: python, django

I would like to count the number of option values in the django admin change_form.html template , which is populated based on user login. ie. Login Superuser will get the count of all items in the dropdown of the foreignkey, while a department member will get the count the items populated from the related foreignkey's dropdown i.e a subset of the foreignkey value instances. How can this be achieved? I have tried 
Code snippet:

```
{% ifequal username 'departuser1' %}
    {%ifequal field.field 'department1'%}
        {{ field.field_set|length }}     #or even 
        {{field.field.option_set.all|length }} #or even
        {{ field.field_set.all }} #or even
        {{ field.field.value_set.all|length }} 
    {% endifequal %}
{% endifequal %}
```

Please help. I always get value 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the change_form.html template use the javascript as below:

```
{% if adminform and add %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var department_count = document.getElementById("{{ adminform.form.department.auto_id }}");
   alert(department_count)
</script>
{% endif %}
```

This will give the options list that have been populated dynamically depending on the login.
Beware to check for the null value that is counted or not.